# How to undo a DataFrame transformed with groupby and assigend to a new variable

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

How can a undo the groupby when assigned to a new object

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3], 'B': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2]})
AA = df.groupby('A')
display(AA.unstack())
```

I get the error:

> Cannot access callable attribute 'reset_index' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

neither with:

```
display(AA.reset_index())
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A simple `head()` will return the whole thing back

```
AA = df.groupby('A')
df_back = AA.head(AA.ngroup().size)

Out[326]:
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  1
2  1  1
3  2  2
4  1  2
5  2  2
6  3  2
```

Comment: @anky_91 head n default 5 , if more than 5 row per group may have problem

Comment: df_back = AA.head(len(AA)+1)    THANK YOU

Comment: @WeNYoBen: good point. I forgot the default `n=5`. I fixed it  :)

Comment: @Joracosu: `len(AA)` returns number of groups which is not correct. You need `ngroup().size`.

Comment: @ansev: `AA.ngroups` returns an integer which is the number of groups which is the same as `len(AA)`

Comment: @ansev: `len(df)` absolutely works :). However, I just assume that OP wants to get back to the original `df` using solely the `AA`

Answer (score 3):

you can put each group in a list and concat like below:

```
pd.concat([g for _,g in AA]).sort_index()
```

---

```
   A  B
0  1  1
1  2  1
2  1  1
3  2  2
4  1  2
5  2  2
6  3  2
```