# View summary of Pandas groupby object

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I'm dealing with a relatively weird architecture right now, and I may receive a group by object (before aggregation functions are applied) while unable to actually see the operation or dataframe that spawned it. I need to somehow recover that information from the groupby object itself. Intuitively to me, that information must be held somewhere in the groupby object, but I cannot see in the documentation how to access it. Does anyone have any information that may be able to help me?

I've tried looking through the documentation for group by objects, as well as using the `.head()` function for group by objects. I would like to recover the columns of the underlying dataframe and what columns are being grouped on.

Comment: You can see what is in the groups simply using such as `for g in df.groupby('col'): print(g)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `df_gby` is your input and from what I can read in the source code, the [`GroupBy`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/main/pandas/core/groupby/groupby.py#L1060) class inherits from [`BaseGroupBy`](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/8cf7ac1a50235b75427033c42468d5b7dd6cd4ed/pandas/core/groupby/ops.py#L541) and the latter can be accessed with the `grouper` attribute that provides access to the grouping information (*including group* `names`) :

```
df_gby = pd._testing.makeMixedDataFrame().groupby(["A", "B"])

>>> type(df_gby)
<pandas.core.groupby.generic.DataFrameGroupBy object at 0x0000017665493250>

>>> type(df_gby.grouper)
pandas.core.groupby.ops.BaseGrouper

>>> df_gby.grouper.names
['A', 'B']
```

And to get the all the columns names, you can use :

```
>>> df_gby.obj.columns
Index(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], dtype='object')
```

*DataFrame used :*

```
     A    B     C          D
0  0.0  0.0  foo1 2009-01-01
1  1.0  1.0  foo2 2009-01-02
2  2.0  0.0  foo3 2009-01-05
3  3.0  1.0  foo4 2009-01-06
4  4.0  0.0  foo5 2009-01-07
```

Comment: This is much more concise than my answer.  I forgot the exact question and went a bit too far, recreating the whole dataframe!  Hopefully useful all the same.

Comment: Thanks @Rawson! Learned from OP question and your answer as well ;)

Comment: And I have just learnt about `pd._testing`!  This is definitely going to help a lot with creating quick generic dataframes to work with.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pd.concat` to return a single dataframe of all the groups, looping through each group and also the `.indices`:

```py
data = pd.concat(
    [v.reset_index(drop=False).set_index(idx_array)
     for (k, v), (g, idx_array) in zip(grouped, grouped.indices.items())]
    ).sort_index()
```

This combines the groups and the original indices, so the initial order of the ungrouped dataframe is not lost.

In fact, a much simpler answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59217791/18571565) by @Andy L.:

```py
grouped.head(grouped.ngroup().size)
```